# senticnet PyPI module not recognized on Mac OS X 11.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm failing to load the senticnet module on macosx-11. Python version I'm using is 3.7 and came through Homebrew.

```
$ sudo python3 -m pip install senticnet
Requirement already satisfied: senticnet in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/senticnet-1.3-py3.7.egg (1.3)
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.10
$ python3
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 27 2021, 02:19:57) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from senticnet.senticnet import SenticNet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/as33/Documents/cgcn/senticnet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from senticnet.senticnet import SenticNet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'senticnet.senticnet'; 'senticnet' is not a package
>>>
```

Any idea what I might be missing? I tried different versions of Python, different versions of senticnet (both 1.3 and 1.6), and even tried both installing it through pip and build from the source.

Comment: You gave your script the same name as the package: don't do that. Python will now import your script, instead of the package. Rename your script.

Comment: Oh damn, I shot myself in the foot,... Thanks for bringing this up to my attention!